# Python 2.7: rounding down instead of rounding up

Tags: python, python-2.7

Rounding up seems easy but I can't figure out how to round down.

Using this code:

```
def __str__(self):
        return'x = %.2f,y = %.2f'%(self.x,self.y)
```

Output:

```
>>> p1 = Point(1.216,3.4582)
>>> print p1
x = 1.22,y = 3.46
```

How can I return x = 1.21 instead of 1.22 and y = 3.45 instead of 3.46?

Comment: something like, import math, return'x = %.2f,y = %.2f' round_down %(self.x,self.y) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
return 'x = %.2f, y = %.2f' % (int(self.x * 100)/100.0, 
                               int(self.y * 100)/100.0)
```

Note that this always rounds towards zero rather than rounding down. This is only important if you need to handle negative values. (i.e. -2.467 will display as -2.46)

Comment: that returns x = 1.00 instead of 1.21

Comment: you need to divide be 100.0 instead of 100 and it will work as advertised

Comment: Ah, you are correct. I was testing using python 3.4 which seems to cast to float implicitly.

Answer (score 1):

Because 1.216 is closer to 1.22 than to 1.21, your code is rounding to 1.22, if you had 1.213 it would have rounded to 1.21. So your function is currently not rounding up but rounding to the nearest one.

What you can do to always round down at two decimals is

```
int(100*x)/100.0
```

which always rounds to zero, or

```
math.floor(100*x)/100.0
```

to always round down.

So you can have:

Normal:

```
def __str__(self):
    return'x = %.2f,y = %.2f'%(self.x,self.y)
```

Always round to zero:

```
def __str__(self):
    return'x = %.2f,y = %.2f'%(int(100*self.x)/100.0,int(100*self.y)/100.0)
```

Always round down:

```
def __str__(self):
    return'x = %.2f,y = %.2f'%(math.floor(100*self.x)/100.0,math.floor(100*self.y)/100.0)
```

Always round up:

```
def __str__(self):
    return'x = %.2f,y = %.2f'%(math.ceil(100*self.x)/100.0,math.ceil(100*self.y)/100.0)
```

Make sure to have

```
import math
```

if you are going to use math.floor or math.ceil.